# How can I redirect my Google App Engine naked domain to www

Tags: google, web-hosting, redirects, google-app-engine

I own a domain klokaffar.se but it doesn't go anywhere if I don't put in www.klokaffar.se. The site is hosted from Google App Engine with a CNAME for the www. Now I want the naked domain to redirect to www but I don't know how to do it. I received this email from my support but I don't know what IP addresses to use for google appengine since I used a CNAME to begin with. Previously there were some IP numbers that we could use, but I don't know what they are. Can you help me? Are the A records the values at [this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2579995)?

> To redirect the domain klokaffar.se to the website on www.klokaffar.se
>   you need to add a name. Please follow this instruction to add a
>   pointer from your domain towards your IP-address:
>   http://www.active24.co.uk/support/content/122/81221/en/how-to-add-an-a_record.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use naked domains with cloud hosting environments like Google AppEngine, because the IP addresses may change at any time so you have to use a CNAME, which you can't do with a naked domain. Some providers have DNS workarounds if you use their own DNS, and Google may do that.

Comment: Amazon AWS Route 53 DNS has "Alias" records where you specify a name (like you would for a CNAME), but the DNS server caches it for some seconds and serves it as an A record.     Those alias records should work fine with any cloud service.